# Run a script on remote server and save output

Tags: linux, shell, redhat

I am setting up two servers: server 1 and server 2. I have written a script which runs on server 1 and saves the output to answer.txt file now I want the same script to run on server 2 and save the output to same file. We use key based login to login from one server to other .
Script destination :- /healthcheck.sh
output file :- /answer.txt

Crontab :-

```
* * * * * /healthcheck.sh &>> /answer.txt
```

I am able to run script on server 1 but not able to figure out a way to save output on same file.

```
#!/bin/sh
hostname
free -m | awk 'NR==2{printf "Memory Usage: %s/%sMB (%.2f%%)\n", $3,$2,$3*100/$2 }'
df -h | awk '$NF=="/"{printf "Disk Usage: %d/%dGB (%s)\n", $3,$2,$5}'
top -bn1 | grep load | awk '{printf "CPU Load: %.2f\n", $(NF-2)}'
systemctl status squid|grep Active
```

I want the answer of both servers in same file.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

ssh -i Key_location.pem host@server '( ~/healthcheck.sh )' >>/answer.txt

healthcheck.sh has to be saved in home directory of the host.

Comment: This is rather unclear to me. "host@server",... what's that? host is not a user usually... 'home directory of the host' is also unclear - usually it is home directory of some user ON some host. Also it does not need not to be saved in the home directory. Also for what the pem file - not explained. Strange to me why my answer is unaccepted and this one accepted afterwards...

Also... you answer your own question  - wtf!!!!

Answer (score 1):

Let's call the server that has the /answer.txt the 'host'. On the host you can just do a redirection to the file like you have with

```
host$ /healthcheck.sh &>> /answer.txt
```

On the other hand, to get the output of some client into the same file with already working key login over ssh, you could login from the client to the host and use ssh to pipe the output:

```
client$ /healthcheck.sh 2>&1 | ssh user@host tee -a /answer.txt
```

Here the "-a" is for appending as with >>.

Kind regards

Comment: Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.

Comment: /answer.txt: Permission denied

Comment: Maybe you first want to have a look at Linux basics before you plan to setup a health-caring system?
sudo chmod 666 /answer.txt makes it writable by all and readable by all users. No idea what your problem with the Pseudo-Terminal is, because I don't know your system configuration.